# File cannot be found in Dynamics CRM project documents

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dynamics-crm

In the latest Dynamics CRM 2016 (online trial version), under **Project Service** > **Projects** > **test project**

[image: Dynamics project CRM navigator]

There seems to be a possibility to add documents to the **test project**

[image: add documents to Dynamics CRM project]

But when we go there, it shows the below error:

[image: could not find file in Dynamics CRM]

We as a laymen, assume that it would allow us to do some kind of file upload.

- From where it's trying to find the files?
- Where do we need to put the files so that it find the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's the SharePoint document area, it will require configuration to work. [Integrate Microsoft Dynamics CRM with SharePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg334768.aspx).